# Call QVector::reserve even if exact number of elements is not known?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

I just had a discussion about `QVector::reserve`. Should it be used even if your estimation of the final size is wrong?

In our specific case the estimate will be off by at least a few elements almost every time. The worst case range of the actual number of elements for an estimate n is [1, 2*n]. Does `reserve` still provide a performance boost or is the penalty of misestimation too big?

Please note that it's not possible for us to use `std::vector` in this case. I don't know if `QVector::reserve` and `std::vector::reserve` do something different.

Comment: Qt docs tell something about the performace: "...if you call resize() often you are likely to get better performance. If size is an underestimate, the worst that will happen is that the QVector will be a bit slower.". IMO, this function will help if you resize your vector frequently, otherwise you will gain not too much.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this type of questions is usually to measure/profile it. Or don't bother if it's not on critical path, since you probably won't even notice the difference.

If you are not low on RAM (and don't really care about it's usage) you can "overreserve" the amount to definitely fit all the elements. If it's not that big, than it'll probably be a minor performance improvement. And if your vector is only filled once and then is just stored somewhere without any modifications, you can just "shrink-to-fit" it later.

Note, however, that `reserve` (both for `QVector` and `vector`) is very frequently used wrong. The only safe place yo call it is *shortly after* you've created the container. It's almost always wrong to call it on "passed in" objects (i.e. function arguments) and often degrades the overall performance.

Comment: What made me skeptical is this line from the docs: "If size is an underestimate, the worst that will happen is that the QVector will be a bit slower." I don't know if that means that the vector will be slower in general. Also I wonder if the call to reserve itself doesn't cost too much if I overestimated by a lot.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on why it might be wrong to call `reserve` on a `std::vector` function argument? Is it because the function can relocate the data?

Comment: @lubgr because `push_back` for vectors is only `O(1)` asymptotically due to the exponential growth strategy. If you manually reserve/resize, you break it. So for example, if you write function like `add_two_elements(vector&,el1,el2)` and inside you reserve/resize for 2 additional elements, then if you run it in a loop, you'll get `O(n^2)` operations (since the vector would be resized on each iteration), while without reserve it'd be just `O(n)` since the vector will grow exponentially. That's why it's only safe to call `reserve` shortly after the code that created the vector.

Comment: @Sebastian.M it most likely just means that if you underestimate the `size` it'll be a bit slower due to several needed "growths".  Not that all operations would somehow be slower in general.